# Ethereum Smart Contract Assembler

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, evm

For learning purposes I would like to write Ethereum Smart Contracts directly in Assembler. By that I mean I want to write the opcodes from the yellow paper somewhere, which then gets converted to bytecode.

However there doesn't seem to be a pure Assembler for the EVM, only inline-assembly in various languages or LLL, which comes close to Assembler.

Is the only way to do this to write my own Assembler? It seems really surprising, since there are so many online disassemblers for it.

Comment: have you found an answer? I am also very curious how to assemble some low level code...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `./evm compile` from the Go Ethereum project (make sure to download the Geth & Tools archive):

https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/